# std::common_type trait for user defined types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, type-traits

Since C++11 the type trait `std::common_type` was introduced. `std::common_type` determines the common type between all of its template arguments. In C++14  its helper type `std::common_type_t` was also introduce in order to make code that uses `std::common_type` type trait shorter.

`std::common_type` is particular useful in overloaded arithmetic operators, e.g.,

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
std::common_type_t<T1, T2> operator+(T1 const &t1, T2 const &t2) {
  return t1 + t2;
}
```

It works fine if its templates arguments are built in types (e.g., `int`, `double`). However I doesn't seem to work if I provide as template arguments to it user defined types e.g.,

```
struct A {};
struct B {};

std::common_type_t<A, B> // doesn't work
```

**Q**: How I can make `std::common_type` trait work with user defined types?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the draft standard [N4582](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/n4582.pdf) *§20.13.2 Header  synopsis [meta.type.synop] (Emphasis Mine)*:

> The behavior of a program that adds specializations for any of the
>   templates defined in this subclause is undefined **unless otherwise
>   specified**.

Consequently, adding specializations for `type_traits` can cause undefined behaviour unless somewhere else in the standard there's a wording for a specific type trait that supersedes the wording displayed above. Fortunately, in *Table 60 - Other transformations*:

[image]

There's the wording:

> A program may specialize this trait if at least one template parameter
>   in the specialization is a user-defined type. [ Note: Such
>   specializations are needed when only explicit conversions are desired
>   among the template arguments. — end note ]

This means that specializations of `std::common_type` type trait that have at least one user-defined type are perfectly allowed. In fact if you take a look at *§20.15.4.3 Specializations of common_type [time.traits.specializations]* you'll find out that STL already defines specializations of `std::common_type` for user defined types `std::chrono::duration` and `std::chrono::time_point`.

Thus, the correct way to make `common_type` "work" for user defined types is to provide a specialization of it for those specific types, e.g.,

```
struct A {};
struct B {};

namespace std {
  template<>
  struct common_type<A, B> {
    using type = A;
  };
}
```

In the code example above we specify that the common type between `A` and `B` is `A`.