# Correct way to restrict functions to specific data types

Tags: c++, boost, mpfr, mpfi

I am currently working with the following data types in c++:

double, boost::interval< double >, and
boost's mpfr/mpfi types (mpfr_float, mpfr_float_50, ..., mpfi_float, mpfi_float_50, ...)

I am writing some overloaded functions for any pair of these types.  The code is identical except for the types in the declaration.

The number of pairs is rather large and I would like to know the most efficient way of taking care of all of these cases (using the vanilla form of templates isn't ideal because only these number types should be allowed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look in `boost/multiprecision/mpfr.hpp` how `mpfr_float_...` is defined.  These types are themselves templates

```
typedef number<mpfr_float_backend<50> >    mpfr_float_50;
typedef number<mpfr_float_backend<100> >   mpfr_float_100;
typedef number<mpfr_float_backend<500> >   mpfr_float_500;
typedef number<mpfr_float_backend<1000> >  mpfr_float_1000;
typedef number<mpfr_float_backend<0> >     mpfr_float;
```

Based on this observation we can easily come up with a template which only matches those types:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/multiprecision/mpfr.hpp>

using boost::multiprecision::number;
using boost::multiprecision::backends::mpfr_float_backend;

template < unsigned size >
void print(number<mpfr_float_backend<size>> const &num)
{
    std::cout << "mpfr_float_" << size << ": " << num << "\n";
}


int main()
{
    using namespace boost::multiprecision;
    mpfr_float_50 a = 1;
    mpfr_float_100 b = 2;
    mpfr_float_500 c = 3;
    double d = 4;

    print(a);
    print(b);
    print(c);
  //print(d); // BOOM!
}
```

You could of course also be a little more general and allow any Boost.Multiprecision type:

```
template < typename... T >
void print(boost::multiprecision::number<T...> const &num)
{
    std::cout << num << "\n";
}
```

Comment: That doesn't allow all number types, you could do `template <typename... T> void print(boost::multiprecision::number<T...> const&)` instead.

Comment: I've added one more suggestion that doesn't focus on a particular library.

Answer (score 2):

I've updated the answer to deal with complex/compound types of your choice.

### Handling Known Numeric Types

Perhaps you don't even care about what library implements the types:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
    std::enable_if_t<
        std::numeric_limits<T>::is_specialized && 
        std::numeric_limits<U>::is_specialized,
        std::common_type_t<T, U>
    > foo(T const& a, U const& b) 
{
    auto product = a * b;
    std::cout << "foo(" << a << ", " << b << ") -> " << product << "\n";
    return product;
}
```

Note this also shows one approach to synthesizing a generic return type.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed28d146ae0ec31b)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/mpfr.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/number.hpp>

template <typename T, typename U>
    std::enable_if_t<
        std::numeric_limits<T>::is_specialized && 
        std::numeric_limits<U>::is_specialized,
        std::common_type_t<T, U>
    > foo(T const& a, U const& b) 
{
    auto product = a * b;
    std::cout << "foo(" << a << ", " << b << ") -> " << product << "\n";
    return product;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::multiprecision;
    mpfr_float_50 a = 1;
    mpfr_float_100 b = 2;
    mpfr_float_500 c = 3;
    double d = 4;

    foo(a, a); foo(b, a); foo(c, a); foo(d, a); std::cout << "\n";
    foo(a, b); foo(b, b); foo(c, b); foo(d, b); std::cout << "\n";
    foo(a, c); foo(b, c); foo(c, c); foo(d, c); std::cout << "\n";
    foo(a, d); foo(b, d); foo(c, d); foo(d, d);
}
```

Prints

```
foo(1, 1) -> 1
foo(2, 1) -> 2
foo(3, 1) -> 3
foo(4, 1) -> 4

foo(1, 2) -> 2
foo(2, 2) -> 4
foo(3, 2) -> 6
foo(4, 2) -> 8

foo(1, 3) -> 3
foo(2, 3) -> 6
foo(3, 3) -> 9
foo(4, 3) -> 12

foo(1, 4) -> 4
foo(2, 4) -> 8
foo(3, 4) -> 12
foo(4, 4) -> 16
```

> Note: the weak point here is `common_type` because it may not know about your library types and hence fail to suggest a proper return type. See [std::common_type trait for user defined types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36523038/stdcommon-type-trait-for-user-defined-types)

### Handling Complex or Compounds

In this case there is no existing type trait to rely on. Also, the types are completely unrelated, so it's not a matter of adding a single partial specialization. In such cases I'd use a custom trait.

> You don't describe much about the kind of operation you'll implement, so let me stick with `foo`. `foo`-ing `A` and `B` should be implemented if `A` and `B` are `foo`-able together.

Let's make a trait to define what types are foo-able. If `foo` is commutative, you need only one "side":

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace mylib { namespace traits {
    //primary template
    template <typename T, typename Enable = void> struct is_fooable : std::false_type {};

    // c++14 style
    template <typename T> constexpr bool is_fooable_v = is_fooable<T>::value;
} }
```

Which you then specialize for whatever type you wish to support:

```
namespace mylib {
    namespace traits {
        template <typename Backend, boost::multiprecision::expression_template_option Et>
            struct is_fooable<boost::multiprecision::number<Backend, Et> >
                : std::true_type {};
        template <typename T>
            struct is_fooable<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>{}> >
                : std::true_type {};
        template <typename T, typename Policies>
            struct is_fooable<boost::numeric::interval<T, Policies> >
                : std::true_type {};
        template <typename T>
            struct is_fooable<std::complex<T> >
                : std::true_type {};
    }

    template <typename T, typename U, typename = std::enable_if_t<traits::is_fooable_v<T> && traits::is_fooable_v<U> > >
    auto foo(T const& a, U const& b) {
        auto product = a * b;
        std::cout << "foo(" << a << ", " << b << ") -> " << product << "\n";
        return product;
    }
}
```

#### Full Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b30be800a9250dc6)</kbd>**

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace mylib { namespace traits {
    //primary template
    template <typename T, typename Enable = void> struct is_fooable : std::false_type {};

    // c++14 style
    template <typename T> constexpr bool is_fooable_v = is_fooable<T>::value;
} }

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <complex>
#include <boost/numeric/interval.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/interval/io.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/mpfr.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/number.hpp>

namespace mylib {
    namespace traits {
        template <typename Backend, boost::multiprecision::expression_template_option Et>
            struct is_fooable<boost::multiprecision::number<Backend, Et> >
                : std::true_type {};
        template <typename T>
            struct is_fooable<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>{}> >
                : std::true_type {};
        template <typename T, typename Policies>
            struct is_fooable<boost::numeric::interval<T, Policies> >
                : std::true_type {};
        template <typename T>
            struct is_fooable<std::complex<T> >
                : std::true_type {};
    }

    template <typename T, typename U, typename = std::enable_if_t<traits::is_fooable_v<T> && traits::is_fooable_v<U> > >
    auto foo(T const& a, U const& b) {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << "foo(" << a << ", " << b << ")";
        return oss.str();
    }
}

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::multiprecision;
    mpfr_float_50 a = 1;
    float c = 3;
    std::complex<double> d(4, 1);
    boost::numeric::interval<int> b(1,1);

    using mylib::foo;
    std::cout << foo(a, a) << "; " << foo(b, a) << "; " << foo(c, a) << "; " << foo(d, a) << "\n";
    std::cout << foo(a, b) << "; " << foo(b, b) << "; " << foo(c, b) << "; " << foo(d, b) << "\n";
    std::cout << foo(a, c) << "; " << foo(b, c) << "; " << foo(c, c) << "; " << foo(d, c) << "\n";
    std::cout << foo(a, d) << "; " << foo(b, d) << "; " << foo(c, d) << "; " << foo(d, d) << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
foo(1, 1); foo([1,1], 1); foo(3, 1); foo((4,1), 1)
foo(1, [1,1]); foo([1,1], [1,1]); foo(3, [1,1]); foo((4,1), [1,1])
foo(1, 3); foo([1,1], 3); foo(3, 3); foo((4,1), 3)
foo(1, (4,1)); foo([1,1], (4,1)); foo(3, (4,1)); foo((4,1), (4,1))
```

Comment: Very nice (+1) but I think `std::common_type` alone would suffice, as now you cannot use `foo` with, e.g. `double` and `std::complex<double>`.

Comment: I've done some tests with this approach, and it seems that it doesn't work with boost::numeric::interval<double> (as was included in the original question).  Do you have any suggestions to make this work?

Comment: I also found that the is_specialized might be too general for my purposes.  I tried to generalize this to work with an ostream operator, and, unfortunately, the is_specialized fails test seems to fail on strings.

Comment: Yeah strings are really not number like. Even if you could interpret them as such, the string type conveys no such information. I never spotted "interval" in the question. I'm not sure what ostream insertion has to do with it either. I'll come back tomorrow and reread the question. Cheers

Comment: Don't worry about the ostream insertion (I should ask that in a separate question).  The interval is more important to me (and relates to the current question).  (+1)

Comment: @MichaelBurr added a more generalist approach. See it [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b30be800a9250dc6). If `foo` is not commutative you might need a treat more like `is_fooable_with<A, B>`